R: row_number not working correctly with pivot_wider?
I’m getting stumped on this one. I have a data frame that I’m trying to reshape into wide form using pivot_wider, but the results aren’t as expected.
My data is currently structured like this:

One column for location (with multiple rows per location, corresponding to repeat surveys),
One column for each of four species detection variables,
One column for each of ten environmental covariates.

In total, it has 1,239 rows x 15 columns. What I want is to "count" the number of surveys at each location using row_number to ultimately produce a data frame that instead has:

One row per location,
One column for each species detection per survey (4 species x 20 surveys = 80 columns),
One column for each covariate.

This should result in a data frame with 76 rows x 91 columns. However, when I attempt to do this, I end up with a data frame that has 1,239 rows x 160 columns. I suspect the issue might be with 'row_number' as it seems to struggle distinguishing between locations with similar names, causing extra rows to be counted for some sites. However, I haven't been able to consistently reproduce this. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?
Here is a (simpler) reproducible example:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

#Sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  Location = c("Site A", "Site A", "Site A", "Site A 1", "Site B", "Site B"),
  Species_1 = c(1,0,1,1,0,1),
  Species_2 = c(0,0,0,1,0,1),
  Species_3 = c(1,1,0,0,1,0),
  Cov_1 = c(10,10,10,20,15,15),
  Cov_2 = c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4)
)

#Group by location and convert data frame to long form
df_wide <- df %>%
  group_by(Location) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
     names_from = row,
     values_from = c(Species_1, Species_2, Species_3),
     names_glue = "{.value}_{row}"
)


This creates a data frame with 6 rows x 12 columns instead of the expected 3 rows x 12 columns. Here is an abbreviated version of what I was hoping to get (without species 2 and 3):



Location
Species_1_1
Species_1_2
Species_1_3
Cov_1
Cov_2




Site A
1
0
1
10
0.1


Site A 1
1
N/A
N/A
20
0.2


Site B
0
1
N/A
15
0.4



Edit: I've already reviewed other entries such as this (How can I pivot a dataframe?) and they do not address the issue of row_number not working correctly with pivot_wider.

What do you want to do with Cov_1 and Cov_2 values, which distinguish the original rows? Drop them? Spread them wide? If the latter, you might want values_from = c(Species_1, Species_2, Species_3, Cov_1, Cov_2),

You say you want one row per location, and one column per covariate. But Site A has three values of Cov_1, and three values of Cov_2. Do you want to show the first one, the average of them, the sum of them, or all of them, or something else?

@JonSpring Thanks for catching that; the covariate measures should be the same for each location. This was a mistake when creating my example. It's been fixed.

@JonSpring Cov_1 and Cov_2 should remain as they were in the original data frame, with one column for each.

That's what I get when I run your code on your new data. I think that resolves it? You might want to run something like count(df, Location, Cov_1, Cov_2) |> count(Location) to see how many Cov_1/Cov_2 values exist for each location. If more than one, the pivot won't work as you intend/expect.
